# I need to make a video that is 480 x 480, is this possible?

Tags: android, camera, resolution, record, screen-size

I currently have a function that checks for all supported video sizes:

```
List<Camera.Size> cameraSizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
for (int i = 0; i < cameraSizes.size(); i++) {

                Camera.Size cs = cameraSizes.get(i);

                Log.i(TAG, cs.width + "x" + cs.height);

                if (cs.width == 640 && cs.height == 480) {

                    VIDEO_WIDTH = 640;
                    VIDEO_HEIGHT = 480;

                    break;

                }else if (cs.width / 4 == cs.height / 3 && cs.width > 480) {

                    VIDEO_WIDTH = cs.width;
                    VIDEO_HEIGHT = cs.height;

                    break;
                }
}
```

Now, if i have the rezolution of 640 x 480 available, is it possible to crop a square of 480x480 and only record that data?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot crop the video stream during recording.

Comment: is it possible then, to atleast show on the video view a cropped video (480x480) even if it recordts on 640x480, and only after finishing the recording to crop the video?